# Can't change my Django model with migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I tried to implement many solutions that I found here, but nothing helps, so I'm looking for an answer.

In my Django project I have Model.py with the following model:

```
class Boat(models.Model):
    boatId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, related_name='boatModels', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    modelName = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None)
    loa = models.FloatField(default=None)
    draftMin = models.FloatField(default=None)
    draftMax = models.FloatField(default=None)
    displacement = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    makerURL = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None)
    videoURL = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Initially I got this error with the latest added field `videoURL`:

> OperationalError at /boats/
> no such column: boat_app_boat.videoURL

Now it is this one:

> OverflowError at /admin/boat_app/boat/edc81b63-d8a5-4ab2-887d-97703554dc4e/change/
> Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

I did mess up with deleting old migrations as some advised, but I think it only made things worse. What is the best way to eventually migrate 'by the book' or if it is impoossible to say, I'd accept advice on how to start from fresh as I only have several items in my database.

Answer (score 1):

because CharField allows 256 char

if it is possible to use FileField and URLField for videoURL and makerURL